# Redirect to Paypal Payment Approval Url results in Error on PayPal page except on IE

Tags: javascript, redirect, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on Payment Processing for an MVC5 website that I am developing. I am using the PayPal SDK. I have credit card payments working just fine on all browsers but when I added support for paying with PayPal accounts I ran into a strange problems.

I create a Payment using the Sdk and then get the Approval Url from it so I can redirect the user to Paypal to authorize the payment. I tried doing the redirect in Javascript by setting:

```
document.location = url
```

and this worked. The user is redirected to Paypal as I wanted. This is where the problem occurred. On ie the user is allowed to authorize the payment, but on any other browser the user is shown the message:

> "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website
>   to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."

The url is definitely correct. On ie I can complete or cancel the payment and am returned to the correct url in my site. On Chrome or Firefox I get the error.

I have read several answers regarding what could cause this error but they all have to do with an incorrect url, the encoding is wrong or the TOKEN has expired. None of them address the issue that the redirect works on IE but gives the error on other browsers. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to show more detail - for the `Redirect` not to happen, the simplest "guess" would be that it's not "hit" (perhaps exception, some other logical flow that prevents it from being hit).

Comment: I'm really more interested in why the document.location call works in ie but generates a PayPal error page in other browsers. If I can just get that to work in all browsers then I can ignore the problem of the Redirect() call not working at all.